# how to set alarm which will ring when the date changes in system

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i am making a app which is using alarm facility for user almost i have done all the parts but there is a problem in my alarm system i explaining this 
-- according to app alarm has to ring  when the date changes not without depending on the time user set

**ex-- let the current time is  4 pm and date is 4 june user wants to set the alarm for 5 june 
  so my alarm will ring on 5 june when date changes in my system.
currently what is happening alarm is ringing on 5 june but on 4pm when the 24 hrs is completed**

Comment: Your time calculation is wrong. you can check the left time and set to alarm. Better is to register time change receiver and check time. You can store the time and ontime you cam compare both.

Comment: plz elaborate it with example or any tutorials